# Relational mutations in Graphql AWS Amplify

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I have the following Graphql schema with relationship, configured with AWS Amplify:

```
type Product @model{
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  name: String!
  img: String!
  components: [Component]! @hasMany
  categories: [Category]! @hasMany
}
type Component @model{
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  name: String!
}
type Category @model{
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  name: String!
}
```

A product can have multiple components and multiple categories.

I would like to have a mutations that can allow me to create a Product and also the components and categories associated.

Amplify codegen already created the mutation "CreateProduct" but it don't allow me to specify the component and category data in order to create them and link to the product.

It seems that i must create the product first and then the component and category separately.

I need to write a custom mutation in order to do what i want or it's impossible?

If it's possible with a custom mutation, how can I write it?

I saw for example that Fauna have this feature, with "create" instruction:
https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/graphql/relationships#mutations

Thank you!